# alternative to use eval python eval-used / W0123

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pylint, flake8

```
d1 = {
        "a": "test"
    }
    
    cmd_dict = {
        "cmd1": "d1['a']",
        "cmd2 : "os.getcwd()"
    }
value = eval(md_dict['cmd1]) 
print(value)
```

Not i will get the value as test.

I am getting pylint error W0123 becasue i am using eval.
is there any way to perform the same without using eval.

Comment: If you want to transport arbitrary Python code as text and have it run… no. Why are you doing that in the first place?

Comment: Is this a purely academic query or is there a real-life use-case for this?

Answer (score 1):

Put functions in your dictionary, and you can simply call them like any other function.  No `eval()` needed:

```
import os

d1 = {}
    
cmd_dict = {
    "cmd1": lambda: d1['a'],
    "cmd2" : os.getcwd,
}

d1['a'] = 'test'

value = cmd_dict['cmd1']()
print(value)  # test
```

Note that `lambda` creates a small anonymous function that will evaluate and return `d1['a']` when it's called; the delayed evaluation (which, again, you do not need `eval()` to do) is why it returns `test` even though that value is set in `d1` after `cmd_dict` has been created.

Comment: thank you very much for the info..sorry i have one further question..if i have all the json data in cmd.json() file..is there any way to specify lambda inside json file                                                                                                 cmd_dict = {
    "cmd1": lambda: d1['a'],
    "cmd2" : os.getcwd,
}                                                                                                                                       
      Exampl  {"cmd1": lambda : d1[a] }

Comment: No -- you probably want to create a Python module rather than putting Python source code inside a JSON file.